# 15 days duration of stay schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, airports, day-counting

I got a Schengen visa from french embassy date: from 7th February /2019 until 8th March /2019 with 15 days duration of stay
my travel plan will be as following :

i will arrive in Paris on the 23rd of February by emirates airlines and i plan to leave Paris on the 7th of March and will arrive in Cairo on 8th of March and my visa valid until the 8th of March

my question : Is my travel plan on point because i don't want to overstay and leave the Schengen area n good terms and i also don't want to get into arguments with the airlines boarding staff

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed itinerary is only 13 calendar days in the Schengen area. Your visa allows you to spend 15 days in the Schengen area. This is perfectly OK.

Your departure from the Schengen area is also the day before the last day of visa validity. This is also perfectly OK. You may remain in the Schengen area until the end of the day (23:59:59) on the date of visa expiration.

There is no problem with this itinerary. Even if there is a problem with your flight and your departure is delayed a day, you still have enough time to leave the Schengen area without overstaying.